# Hide the Update Manager tray icon after applying security updates?

Tags: linux-mint, software-updates

The Update Manager icon will show up in the system tray if you have **any** updates available, but sometimes I just like to install security updates and ignore the software updates:

[image]

Is there to make the icon disappear until I have **new** updates available, not just **any** updates available.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the "Include updates which require the installation of new packages or the removal of installed package" option under the 'preferences' of 'Edit' menu.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work.